# STM32CubeIDE .ld files font colors

Tags: eclipse, stm32cubeide

On STM32CubeIDE (IDE based on eclipse, from ST), i don't find any options to change the font color for some files like linker scripts (for C/C++ Files it's ok). It's very difficult to read the file and i would like to use the dark theme.

Maybe one of you is aware of the eclipse font options possibilities ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I quickly found a workaround solution changing the File Associations.

Go to Preference,General,Editors,File Associations.

Select Text Editor in Open unassociated file with:
Then, select *.ld and change Associated editors.

I selected C/C++ Editor and now the .ld file is easier to read.

[image]

[image]